# failed to mock function in the python

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing

I have a simple python code in the VS Code.

under a package my, there are two files aa.py and test_aa.py

aa.py

```
# Function to be tested
def add(a, b):
    return a + b
```

test_aa.py

```
from unittest.mock import MagicMock, patch
from my.aa import add

# Test case using MagicMock to mock the add function
@patch('my.aa.add')
def test_add_with_mock(mock_add):
    # Set the return value of the mocked add function
    mock_add.return_value = 10

    # Now any call to the add function will return the value set in the mock
    result = add(3, 5)

    # Assert that the add function was called with the correct arguments
    mock_add.assert_called_once_with(3, 5)

    # Assert the result of the add function
    assert result == 10

# Run the test
test_add_with_mock()
```

When I debug to run this unit test, result is 8 rather than 10, seem the mock doesn't work. I am confuse why it fails to mock add().

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: assert ```3 + 5 == 10```?  Not to sound facetious, but really?  Is this base 8 addition?

Comment: @ewokx it is just showing that the mock didn't apply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that you used:

```
from my.aa import add
```

So, you have a reference to the original `add` before it got patched. And that's what you call when you do `result = add(3, 5)`.

Instead try:

```
from my import aa

def test(...):
    ...
    result = aa.add(3, 5)
```

Now your test should lookup the name "add" from the "aa" module namespace, which is where it got patched.

Comment: for "from my.aa import add", why do you say it refers to original add() before it got patched?

Comment: The import statement gets a reference on `add` while `test_aa.py` is loading. That is _before_ the patch is applied, which happens when `test_add_with_mock` gets called later. So at the time you import, it isn't patched yet. You could also verify this by moving the import statement inside the test function, instead of at the top of the module...

Comment: make sense. Thanks

Comment: @wim just for my understanding, changing to `@patch('__main__.add')` also seems to work, is this not encouraged?

Comment: @python_user In practice, you wouldn't usually patch the same function you're actually calling in the test, that's somewhat pointless (the test would not actually be covering anything). You usually patch out some piece that the function under test is using.